# Why was the Dragon Fractal in the Jurassic Park novel?

Tags: jurassic-park

Within the Jurassic Park novel, in between various chapters, we see inset images of a fractal being drawn.  Specifically, this is the [Dragon Fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve).  I'll spare the details about this specific fractal but, suffice to say, we see the first iteration early in the book, and after every chapter (or possibly 2 or 3, I can't recall) we see another inset of the next iteration.

I also seem to recall that under each iteration there might have been a quote from Ian Malcolm, often regarding chaos theory since it is one of the central themes of the story.

I was 16 when I read the novel shortly after the film was released and I've not picked it up since then.  I recall being fascinated with the fractal images because I'd thumbed through the book and seen them before I even began reading.  This made me curious about the fractals purpose, but to my recollection, the inclusion of the fractal was never really explained and I recall being a bit frustrated about not understanding why it was there to begin with.  Yes, it was a neat set of mathematics, but I failed to see it's purpose.

So, why did Crichton include the drawing of the fractals in the book?  What purpose did the illustration serve within the story? It might be obvious but as a 16 year old, and since then, I've never figured out the purpose for including the images in a story about dinosaurs "finding a way" to survive when they had been engineered to be incapable of reproduction.

Comment: It's to symbolise chaotic patterns

Comment: Fractals and chaos are very closely related, and were often lumped together in popular discussions of mathematics around the time the book came out.

Comment: Here's an interesting video on the matter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCyC-K_PnRY

Comment: @Valorum I'll be honest. I could kind of read between the lines and get that, however, it seemed like a rather forced explanation to include a computationally drawn image. The inclusion, to me, felt like Crichton saw a fractal one day and simply said "That's cool! Let me throw one in my next novel!" I'm kind of hoping that some where there's a better, more thorough explanation than that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: *"“No,” Malcolm said. “It's the only way to look at things. At least, the only way that is true to reality. You see, the fractal idea of sameness carries within it an aspect of recursion, a kind of doubling back on itself, which means that events are unpredictable. That they can change suddenly, and without warning.”*"

Comment: @Valorum, you wizard.  I have no clue how you know so much about so many Sci-Fi stories.  Anyway, at 16 that sentence would have flown over my head.  That helps a bit.  Also, FuzzyBoots answer includes a single word (reptile) that helps me consider why, of all fractals, the "dragon" fractal might have been chosen.  Dragons are certainly reptilian as were the dinosaurs of Jurassic Park.  That's something I'd never considered as the reason for selecting this specific fractal.

Comment: @RLH He's not a wizard, just has a lot of skill with Google and Ctrl+F ;-)

Comment: Because 'Dinosaurs are Dragons' (trope link omitted)?

Answer (score 12):

I have not found anything from Crichton himself, but the theory [here](https://rohanurich.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/the-dragon-curve-and-a-bit-on-fractals/) makes sense to me.

> Each chapter (or iteration as the book called it) was found to have a seemingly meaningless illustration of some lines and squares adjunct to a quotation from one the book’s characters.
>
> The First Chapter/First Iteration contained the above image with the quote: “At the earliest drawings of the fractal curve, few clues to the underlying mathematical structure will be seen.” Ian Malcolm.
>
> With each subsequent chapter, the quotations begin to resemble the events in the story – the idea of unpredictability; chaos theory – and the illustrations become more elaborate – and eerily reptilian.

So basically, it's about simple systems that rapidly become more complex as we look more closely at them. In the case of the Park, more complex in a deadly fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted it as a metaphor for DNA; like a fractal, it keeps duplicating itself to build a bigger version of something (organism).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure you're clear on what a fractal is; a fractal is self-similar, while DNA isn't in the same sense.